# Alignment for types with fixed bit length on QNX

Tags: c++, gnu, memory-alignment, qnx

On Windows `uint16_t` is just a `typedef` of `unsigned short` (from VS2017 `stdint.h`):

```
typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;
```

But on QNX6 with GCC `uint16_t` from `stdint.h` refers to `_Uint16t`:

```
typedef _Uint16t           uint16_t;
```

which is declared in `include\sys\compiler_gnu.h` as following:

```
typedef unsigned int                _GCC_ATTR_ALIGN_u16t __attribute__((__mode__(__HI__)));
typedef _GCC_ATTR_ALIGN_u16t        _Uint16t __attribute__((__aligned__(2)));
```

What's the reason to make `uint16_t` aligned in that case?

The question is came from the code below:

```
 using T = uint16_t;
 std::map<T, unsigned char> m;
```

Which gives me a warning:

> ```
> warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'T {aka short unsigned int}' 
> [-Wignored-attributes]
> ```

Should I switch back to `using T = unsigned short;` to prevent such a warning?

Comment: What version of QNX are you using? What is the gcc version?

Comment: @Red.Wave I cross-compile application on Windows via gcc 5.5 for QNX6.5

Comment: Can you remove the "-Wignored-attributes" switch from compile options?

Comment: @Red.Wave sure, but I don't see a reason to do so. I would like to know why `uint16_t` is aligned on QNX.

Comment: A realtime OS with a claim on speed.